# Creating a list after clicking on a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have been researching the internet and can't find anything on what I need exactly. Basically what I'm trying to do is allow the user to come to a table view controller and select from the list like below with choosing your brand. Once you select the brand it stores the value into the cell and allows you to choose a model. How do I programmatically present the user with more options once he/she has chosen from the previous item? The photos below help show what I mean, I don't have any code since I don't know where to start. I thank you for any help in advance!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Here is my updated code as of 8/14/2014:

This is the select Make view controller:

```
#import "MakeTableViewController.h"


@interface MakeTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MakeTableViewController {
    NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.carMakes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Acura", @"Aston Martin", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.carMakes count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.carMakes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    AddCarTableViewController *controller = [[AddCarTableViewController alloc] init];
    controller.makeName = [self.carMakes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    controller.makeLabel.text = controller.makeName;
    NSLog(@"%@", controller.makeName);
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

My code for the AddCarTableViewController is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.makeLabel.text = self.makeName;

    return cell;
}
```

Nothing is displaying still which is weird.

Comment: the screenshots show a very basic UI flow. The user clicks on a cell, it presents a new screen screen with a UITableView with a bunch of options. The user picks a cell and what is selected is passed back (probably via a delegate) - so I not sure what you are asking here

Comment: You need to search for "UINavigationController" and "UITableView" and "passing data from one controller to another". You can find many questions on SO as well.

Comment: Your answers are in Apple's documentations in [UINavigationController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UITableViewController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comments I'll research based on what you have told me.

Comment: Please give more details on the "options" part of your question.

Comment: @SrinivasanN I have been trying to figure this out I have read the documentation on Apple. I just don't understand how to take the selected item and bring it into the previous view. Above you select "Choose your brand" once you click it performs a segue to a table view then you select "Audi" and it dismisses the tableview and stores it into the same cell that says "Brand" how do I transfer the selected item to the previous view?

Comment: Are you sure each of the screens you are showing above are views and not individual viewcontrollers? and if the value has to be passed between views of single viewcontroller its quite basic. There are variety of ways a value can be passed within a module and between viewcontrollers. Instead of me giving out a answer straight away, why dont you take time to find and learn on passing values between UITableViews (or) passing values between viewcontrollers, so that you'll be able to decide on which method to adapt.

Comment: @SrinivasanN I think I'm getting closer, can you let me know if I am closer to getting this working? You don't have to give me the answer yet as long as I know I'm on the right track I will continue to try and figure it out. I'll update my code above.

Comment: @Derek Saunders - It looks like you are doing good. :-)

Comment: @SrinivasanN I'm still confused and can't seem to display the text can you give me a hint as to what's going on? My updated code is above.

Comment: Don't you already have an instance of add car vc when user selects the make?

Comment: Yes but nothing shows up. Which is what I'm not understanding @hackerinheels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are creating a new instance on AddCarTableVC and setting the make in that

What u need to do is get the reference to the alreAdy visible instance ans update it on that instance.

You could do that via delegates or a shared data model.. Or passing the reference to the label to the makeVc to set in (not preferred)

Hope this helps.

I think we did work out a delegate set up in another ques u asked .. Just use that

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help me, looks like I'll just use a delegate then.