# Using a delegate to transfer data

Tags: ios, ios7, delegates, tableview

I have a view controller with a static cell named 'Make' I have two controllers one called "AddCarTableViewController" and "MakeTableViewController" when you click on the static cell named 'Make' it presents the make table view controller where you can select the make, then pops the view controller and am trying to store the selected value in the detailTextLabel of the static cell. here is my code for all the controllers.

The problem I'm having is once I select the make everything happens as it should I even log the selected item and it saves it after popping the view controller, but I can't figure out how to implement selected item into the detailTextLabel. Any help will be much appreciated!

"MakeTableViewController.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AddCarTableViewController.h"

@protocol CarMakeDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)updateCarMake:(NSString *)updateMake;
@end


@interface MakeTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *carMakes;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CarMakeDelegate> delegate;



@end
```

MakeTableViewController.m

```
#import "MakeTableViewController.h"


@interface MakeTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation MakeTableViewController {
    NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.carMakes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Acura", @"Aston Martin", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.carMakes count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.carMakes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    oldIndexPath = indexPath;

    NSString *addMake = self.carMakes[indexPath.row];
    [self.delegate updateCarMake:addMake];

    NSLog(@"%@", addMake );

    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


@end
```

AddCarTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MakeTableViewController.h"


@interface AddCarTableViewController : UITableViewController 

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *makeName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *makeCell;


@end
```

AddCarTableViewController.m

```
#import "AddCarTableViewController.h"

@interface AddCarTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation AddCarTableViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 4;
}

-(void)updateCarMake:(NSString *)updateMake {

    self.makeCell.detailTextLabel.text = updateMake;
}
@end
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question properly. Are you trying to pass data `make` from `MakeTableViewController` to `AddCarTableViewController` ?

Comment: Can you post the code you have for `-[AddCarTableViewController tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]`? I think it has something to do with the reference you have to the `makeCell`.

Comment: @JasonBarker this is what i have for cellForRowAtIndexPath - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    return cell;
}

Comment: @DerekSaunders if that is your implementation of `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, where do you return the `makeCell` as a cell in the table?

Comment: @jasonbarker I put it in the -(void)updateCarMake implementation.

Comment: @DerekSaunders, yes, I saw that. But to get the `makeCell` into the `UITableView`, you would need to return the reference to it in a `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` function. Otherwise, I don't understand how you would ever see that custom cell in the table.

Comment: @jasonbarker So the code that I have so far is it valid? Once the user is selecting the make and the viewController is popped it's storing the value right? What function would I use inside the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath to call upon my delegate?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use delegate in this case. Just update the underlying data model. and call

```
[tableview reloadData];
```

When the makeViewController is popped.

In the AddCarVC's cellForRowAtIndex, add another line to check if current indexPath corresponds to Make cell and if it does update the detailLabel text.

Comment: I tried that, but they are static cells and doesn't even show when i put [self.tableView reloadData]; Can you take a look at this code I have done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24826327/creating-a-list-after-clicking-on-a-cell?noredirect=1#comment39393123_24826327